# Prestashop - how to set custom tax for products of one manufacturer?

Tags: database, prestashop

My prestashop site has different manufacturers and I want to set 20% TAX/VAT for products of one manufacturer and don't effect the rest of manufacturers. Which way and how could I do it? Let's say the manufacturer identified by it's id - manufacturer_id = 1.

Comment: which solution or ideas did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop ps
        LEFT JOIN
    ps_product p ON ps.id_product = p.id_product 
SET 
    ps.id_tax_rules_group = XXX
WHERE
    p.id_manufacturer = 1;
```

replace XXX with actual tax rules id.
You need to repeat this update query for ps_product table to have consistent data.

Answer (score 0):

must be online file upload on your website and call

> > require_once('config/defines.inc.php');
> >
> > $id_tax_rules = XXXX; // ID TAX RULES GROUP
> >
> > $id_manufacturer = 1; // ID MANUFACTURER
> >
> > Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_shop SET id_tax_rules_group = '.$id_tax_rules.' WHERE id_manufacturer = '.$id_manufacturer);
> >
> > Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product SET id_tax_rules_group = '.$id_tax_rules.' WHERE id_manufacturer = '.$id_manufacturer);
> >     ?>

Regards